# Can't mass-assign protected attributes whit fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im try use this form on create product:

this is into the product_form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :feature do |ft| %>
    <%= ft.label :name %>
    <%= ft.text_field :name %>  
    <%= ft.label :value %>
    <%= ft.text_field :value %>
<% end %>
```

But when try create im get this error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: feature
```

Im try put this in my Product model:

```
 attr_accessible :code, :description, :price, :title,:image_1,:image_2,:image_3,:image_4,:image_5,:image_6,:image_7,:image_8,:features_attributes # and feature_attributes meet


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :features
```

but get the same error, my association is

product.rb

```
  has_many :features
```

feature.rb

```
  belongs_to :product
```

i see the nested attributes class but dont found because what the error persists:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

the error is:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: feature
```

if someone can helpe im thanks very very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
fields_for :features
```

**EDIT**

The name of the first argument should be the name of your association (features) and then the second argument should be the instance of your object. So you have to wrap this part in a loop like this:

```
<% @product.features.each do |feature| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :features, feature do |ft| %>
    <%= ft.label :name %>
    <%= ft.text_field :name %>  
    <%= ft.label :value %>
    <%= ft.text_field :value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: get this error: `No association found for name `name'. Has it been defined yet?
`

Comment: Well this solve, but now the form dont show on my new_product_form hmm

Comment: =/, dont showing man, im try meet put in the controller `    @product = Product.new
    @feature = @product.feature.new
` and call this in form but dont display